# How to make part of header a different colour to the rest?

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

I have a really basic header with 2 lists of "buttons"; one on the left and one of the right. The thing is, I want the "Sign Up" button to have a different background color to the rest (any color). I have an example below and my actual header below, along with my code.

**What I want:**
[image]

**What I have:**
[image]

```
    <!-- html: -->
```

```css
header {
  min-height: 20px;
}

header a {
  color: #3b4b5d;
  text-decoration: none;
}

section h1 {
  margin: 0;
}


/* TOP NAV CSS */

.top-nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-logo img {
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 20px 12px 20px 20px;
}

.left-nav ul li {
  margin: 10px 16px 0px 16px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 24px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

header a:hover {
  color: #50E3C2;
}

.right-nav ul li {
  margin: 10px 16px 0px 16px;
  padding: 0px 24px 0px 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="top-nav">
    <div id="branding">
      <a href="index.html" class="nav-logo"><img src="assets/nav-bar-logo.png" alt="trooops-logo"></a>
    </div>

    <nav class="left-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="discover.html">Discover</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="right-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.html">Log In</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: make it simple - add a class in your "Sign Up" button and set the background color with css

Comment: Could you please provide an example? Would be a huge help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

```
.right-nav>ul>li:first-child{
    background-color: #whatever-color
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qm3ofgbu/)

**Edit**
I modified the fiddle and put some rules as an example. I think you're kind of messing around with padding and margins. Re-applied rules to the anchors, as suggested by @Robert. Take the fiddle as a suggestion, not the complete solution. That is up to you ;)

Edited fiddle: [newFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qm3ofgbu/2/)

Comment: I would assign the background color to the anchor in the list item vs the list item itself though.

Comment: This is great but it only adds a background colour to the region that the text is in. That doesn't fill the header height. Imagine a small box around the exact size of the Sign Up text.

Answer (score 1):

To expand what @sissy provided, since your anchor ( tag) is the clickable element, and your styling it like a button, it makes sense to assign your color to that element.  Use padding to give some room around the text.

```css
header {
  min-height: 20px;
}

header a {
  color: #3b4b5d;
  text-decoration: none;
}

section h1 {
  margin: 0;
}


/* TOP NAV CSS */

.top-nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-logo img {
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 20px 12px 20px 20px;
}

.left-nav ul li {
  margin: 10px 16px 0px 16px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 24px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

header a:hover {
  color: #50E3C2;
}

.right-nav ul li {
  margin: 10px 16px 0px 16px;
  padding: 0px 24px 0px 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}

.right-nav>ul>li:first-child a {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 12px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="top-nav">
    <div id="branding">
      <a href="index.html" class="nav-logo"><img src="assets/nav-bar-logo.png" alt="trooops-logo"></a>
    </div>

    <nav class="left-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="discover.html">Discover</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="right-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.html">Log In</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

css:

```
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

html:

```
<a href="#" class="button">Link Button</a>
```